# Index duplication error caused by tokenizing an optional argument in a macro

Tags: macros, indexing, xparse, optional-arguments

I'm trying to create a command `\term` for printing a definition and then indexing it. It has one optional argument and one mandatory argument; if the optional argument is absent, the mandatory argument is used in its place. Here's the code I have:

```
% .tex file
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeindex
\NewDocumentCommand{\term}{o m}{
    {\bfseries #2}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{
        \index{#2}
    }{
        \index{#1}
    }
 }

\begin{document}
A \term[pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum]{$\pi_*$-boojum} is\dots

Now I'm going to index $\pi_*$-boojum again.\index{pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The problem is, these two entries are displayed separately in the index:

[image]

Looking at the `.ind` file pinpoints the problem:

```
% .ind file
\begin{theindex}

  \item $\pi _*$-boojum, 1
  \item $\pi_*$-boojum, 1

\end{theindex}
```

I think the source of this issue is that `\IfNoValueTF` tokenizes the optional argument, inserting the space between `\pi` and `_*`. Then, `makeindex` treats `\pi _*` and `\pi_*` as different things.

Hence, my question is: **is there a way to use the mandatory argument as the default value of an optional argument without tokenizing the optional argument?** *A priori* it should be possible to check whether a string is empty without processing it, but I'd also be content to know that it's impossible in LaTeX.

Here are some things I tried:

- Using `\IfNoValueTF` as above
- Using `\@dblarg` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351401/55879)
- Using the `ifmtarg` package.
- Wrapping in `\mbox` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176445/55879)
- Using `\detokenize` as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20064/55879)

Comment: Aside: with an up-to-date `xparse` you can do `{O{#2}m}`.

Comment: @JosephWright this code is part of a project with multiple collaborators, not all of whom have an up-to-date version of `xparse`. If nothing else works, I'll use that, but I'd prefer a solution that works on a wider range of distributions. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Won't help with the matter at hand, in terms of tokenization, but won't hurt either: I was just noting in case you have simpler use cases where it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem here isn't `xparse`, it's `\index`, or rather trying to read already-tokenize material. The latter quite deliberately reads arguments more-or-less verbatim. As with all verbatim things, this only works if the input has not previously been tokenized. To do that *and* wrap `\index` into another command, you will have to do a verbatim read. We don't have 'verbatim optional arguments' in `xparse` (at least at the moment!), so one might do something like

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\term}{t[}{%
  \IfBooleanTF#1{\termauxi]}{\termauxii}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\termauxi{vm}{%
  \index{#1}%
  {\bfseries #2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand\termauxii{v}{%
  \index{#1}%
  {\bfseries\scantokens{#1}}%
}
```

The above yields `.idx` file

```
\indexentry{pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum}{1}
\indexentry{pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum}{1}
\indexentry{$\pi_*$-boojum}{1}
```

from the input in the question plus a third test line:

```
A \term[pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum]{$\pi_*$-boojum} is\dots

Now I'm going to index $\pi_*$-boojum again.\index{pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum}

A \term{$\pi_*$-boojum} is \dots
```

Of course, `\scantokens` can be a bit risky but it does allow us to have a more-or-less verbatim mandatory argument ...

Comment: This does not solve my problem. I would like both entries to map to the same index entry `pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum` (e.g. if they were on different pages, I would get a single index entry listing those two pages), rather than one mapping to `$\pi_*$-boojum` (indexed under `$`) and the other mapping to `pistar-boojum@$\pi_*$-boojum` (indexed under `p`).

Comment: @ArunDebray See updated approach

Comment: I've used `xparse` here as it was in the question but since we need low-level verbatim manipulation one might simply go with `\@ifnextchar` plus `\@sanitize`  and do it all 'by hand'.

Comment: The updated version looks like it works. Thanks so much!